# ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq crashes when one group does not have enough data points

Tags: r, ggpmisc

```r
library(ggpmisc)
data <- mpg
table(data$class)
data$class[mpg$class=="2seater"] <- c(rep("2seater", 1), rep("compact", 4))
formula <- y ~ x + I(x^2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = formula) +
  ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq(aes(label =  paste(stat(eq.label), stat(adj.rr.label), sep = "*\", \"*")),
               formula = formula, parse = TRUE)
```

The above code will produce a plot without the formula and r-squared labels. And will give this warning:

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_poly_eq()`:
argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

The problem stems from the fact that the `2seater` color group only has one data point. It isn't enough. But then it should at least output labels for the other groups?

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed a bug in `stat_poly_eq()`. Can you please raise an issue at https://github.com/aphalo/ggpmisc/issues ?
You can just copy this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is now fixed in upcoming 'ggpmisc' (0.4.0), which can be installed from GitHub. At the moment the fixed version can be installed with `remotes::install_github("aphalo/ggpp")` followed by `remotes::install_github("aphalo/ggpmisc")`.

Once both packages are in CRAN updating 'ggpmisc' will be enough.

Comment: Any expectations of when it will be out on CRAN?

Comment: I would expect early next week. I will get it ready for CRAN submission during the coming weekend at the latest, and hopefully it will pass the automatic checks without delay.